# The onsubmit function doesn't seems to work when I submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, onsubmit

Hi i try to call a function with the onsubmit property, but nothing happen.
Here, it's just a test, to make the function work but, i would like to verify if the phone number is correct.
Before I used simple alert, but everytime it's refreshing the page and I don't like it, so I search a little bit and found the " onsubmit " but doesn't work  ..
What did i do wrong ? I use JS and PHP. Thank you all !

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Mon test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="/CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function valide_GSM() {
      alert("Ca fonctionne");
      document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return valide_GSM();">
    <table class="tableauInscription">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;">Formulaire d'inscription</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Prenom :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtPrenom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Prenom"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Nom :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtNom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nom"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Adresse email :</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="txtAdresseMail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">GSM min 7 :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtGSM" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="GSM" minlength="7"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Identifiant :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtIdentifiant" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Mot de passe : </td>
        <td><input type="Password" name="txtMotDePasse" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche"></td>
        <td style="padding-left:33px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
          <button type="submit" id="btnCreerCompte" class="btn btn-dark">Créer le compte</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I see the "Ca fonctionne" alert.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? What is `type="TextBox"` or `CssClass=...`?

Comment: @Aaron The alert don't pop up, the page just refresh and the input are blank

Comment: @brombeer Yes i use Bootstrap 4

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't use `type="TextBox"` or `CssClass`! And I too get the popup when running that code snippet

Comment: document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();, there is no element with id txtGSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();` is throwing an error so your function never gets to `return false` which stops the form from submitting.

There is no element with that ID. You need to add that ID to that element.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Mon test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="/CSS/StyleAccueil.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function valide_GSM() {
      alert("Ca fonctionne");
      document.getElementById("txtGSM").focus();
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return valide_GSM();">
    <table class="tableauInscription">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;">Formulaire d'inscription</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Prenom :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtPrenom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Prenom"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Nom :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtNom" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nom"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Adresse email :</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="txtAdresseMail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Adresse email"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">GSM min 7 :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtGSM" id="txtGSM" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="GSM" minlength="7"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Identifiant :</td>
        <td><input type="TextBox" name="txtIdentifiant" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche">Mot de passe : </td>
        <td><input type="Password" name="txtMotDePasse" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="coteGauche"></td>
        <td style="padding-left:33px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
          <button type="submit" id="btnCreerCompte" class="btn btn-dark">Créer le compte</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there anywhere where i can get in touch with you ? I'd like to ask you 1 or 2 thing if you don't mind ?

Comment: @KingFlamini You may reach me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236090/68818123) for the next few minutes.

Comment: oh sorry i was away :(